# How to check if files exist on different drive with Nodejs

Tags: node.js

I am working on a Nodejs powered system that runs within a local network and I need to check if files exist on a different local drive of the computer that the Nodejs app runs on.

I have tried using the fs.exists function, but that doesn't.
Is this possible? I am guessing there are security risks involved, but because the system runs 100% on a local network, is there any work around to achieve this?

the reason I need to check that the files exist is because the file name holds the version number, and I need to get the latest version (highest number)

this is what I tried:

```
// the example looks for example#1.wav in the V:\public folder
var filename = "example"

var versionCount = 1;
if (fs.existsSync("V:\public\"+filename+"#"+versionCount+".wav")) {
    console.log("V:\public\"+filename+"#"+versionCount+".wav Found!");
    } else {
        console.log("V:\public\"+filename+"#"+versionCount+".wav does not exists");
    }
```

I am running Nodejs on Windows.

Any suggestions would be greatly apprecaited! TIA!

Comment: Please describe your environment. What platform are you running on? Operating System? What drive? What drive are you trying to access? And please post example code that illustrates your problem. Thanks.

Comment: @RobRaisch you are right, I should have provided more info. I have updated my question.

Comment: What WIndows user are you running your node process as and does that user have read access to V:\public?

Comment: I am running nodejs by running "node [scriptName].js" in cmd, so I am guessing that the user is the user I am logged in with. This user has read/write access to the V:\public folder

Comment: What happens when you try to access that drive from within the node CLI?

Comment: So the problem was that I was using backslashs (\) instead of forwardslashs (/), thanks for taking the time to try and help!

Answer (score 1):

Posting an answer incase anyone runs into the same problem in the future..

I resolved this problem by using forward slashes (/) instead of back slashes ()

Comment: I can resolve similar problem by changing slash. Previously, it works fine if we refer to file/folder in the same drive with backslash. For different drive, we need to change from backslash to forwardslash.